# Cannot get the token from request in the controller

Tags: java, spring, token

I'm trying to test a loginController in Spring and I cannot get the token from the request.
In my test

```
   private CsrfToken token; 
   HttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();

     @Before
     public void setUp() throws Exception {        
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();        
         token = new DefaultCsrfToken("1", "a", "b"); 
         request.setAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName(), token); 
     }

    @Test
    public void testCtrlCorrecltyHandlesPassword() throws Exception {         
        CsrfToken token2 = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());

        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/login")
                .param("name", name)
                .param("password", password)
                .param("request", request.toString())
                //.sessionAttr("request", request)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
    }
```

When I debug I see that token2 has been created successfully and I'm getting it's value from request but in the controller when I try with the exact same way

```
CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
```

is null.

I also tried `.sessionAttr("request", request)` and `@ModelAttribute("request")HttpServletRequest request` as a parameter in the controller but it doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my question in case anyone can help me on this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually...

```
    MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
    session.setAttribute("token", token);

    MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/login").session(session)
            .header("X-Csrf-Token", "")
            .requestAttr(CsrfToken.class.getName(), token)
            .param("name", name)
            .param("password", password)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
```